# java regex for "any symbol" that's neither word nor number nor space

Tags: java, regex

As the title says: I want the input to be one or more symbols that is not in the union of letters, numbers and white space. So basically any of `~!@#, etc`. I have

```
"^(?=.*[[^0-9][^\w]])(?=\\S+$)$"
```

I know I could negate the appropriate set, but I don't know how to create my super set to start with. Would the following do?

```
"^(?=.*[(_A-Za-z0-9-\\+)])(?=\\S+$)$"
```

Comment: Provide more input and expected behaviour

Answer (score 4):

Maybe you're looking for `\p{Punct}`, which matches any of `` !"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[]^_`{|}~ ``.

```
String re = "\\p{Punct}+";
```

Answer (score 3):

The class:

```
[^\w\s]
```

This will match any non-alphanumeric/non-whitespace character.

Java `String`:

```
String regex = "[^\\w\\s]";
```

Comment: That doesn't do what you think it does. I believe you were thinking of `[^\w\s\d]` - `[\W\S\D]` matches everything. It's like "Give me everything that is not a banana, or not an orange". Well, banana is not an orange, so here you go.

Comment: *Now* the `\d` is redundant. `[^\s\w]` will be sufficient.

Comment: I blame being sick. Thanks all

Comment: Note that this will match non printable characters too

Comment: And remember the \w also matches the `_` which is a symbol.

Answer (score 1):

To match a string of one or more non letter, non number or non white space you with a regex you could use:

`^(?:[^\w\s]|_)+$`

[image]

You have to include the `_` separately because the character class \w includes the `_`. And the `\w` character class is equivalent to `[a-zA-Z_0-9]` [reference link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/pre_char_classes.html)

Answer (score 0):

I would just use a [Character](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html) object to keep it simple.

Something like this:

```
public String getSpecialSymbols(String s) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
        Character c = s.charAt(i);
        if (!c.isDigit() && !c.isWhitespace() && !c.isLetter()) {
            sb.append(c);
        }
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

This would be even more straightforward:

```
public String getSpecialSymbols(String s) {
    String special = "!@#$%^&*()_+-=[]{}|'\";\\:/?.>,<~`";
    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
        String c = s.substring(i, 1);
        if (special.contains(c)) {
            sb.append(c);
        }
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```